# Why does nginx return a 403 error on the index.php file?

Tags: php, nginx, webserver, virtualhost, http-status-code-403

Calling "http://test.local/" in the browser returns a "403 Forbidden" error.
Calling "http://test.local/index.php" works well.

If I create a "index.html" file, calling "http://test.local/" shows me the "index.html" file correctly.

So just the "index.php" file doesn't work.

This is my vhost configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.local;
  root /var/www/public;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

The error.log file contains this error:

```
2013/12/28 14:00:57 [error] 2854#0: *50 directory index of "/var/www/public/" is forbidden, client: 10.0.2.2, server: test.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "test.local"
```

Why's that? I've googled a lot now and checked permissions (which are all set to 777) and tried lots of other stuff too, but I don't get it working.

I'm new to nginx so probably I'm just missing something.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration seems fine, but I think it can be simplified, try this

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.local;
  root /var/www/public;
  index index.php;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try to reload nginx ?

Comment: I was able to get it running somehow - by completely reinstalling the virtual machine and now it works, although I think I didn't change anything relevant. Not sure what the reason was. If I find out I'll report back.